# Auto upload photos directly from SD card to the cloud

Tags: sd-card, photos, cloud, onedrive

I've an SD card reader attached to my android tablet. During traveling I want to backup my camera photos from the camera's SD card directly into the cloud (e.g. OneDrive) without storing them on the tablet (since there is not enough memory on it). Is this possible?

Comment: What have you already tried? There are e.g. filemanager apps with integrated cloud access that can upload files.

Comment: Haven't tried those ones - or didn't see that my "File Manager" manager have such feature. Worth a search with this new approach